# How to share web dirver in protractor with cucumber frame work

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, protractor, cucumber

I have angular project, where in which I am implementing browser based test cases, using protractor testing tool with cucumber framework, I successfully able to run login test cases, now trying to implement other set of test cases, say after login,  dashboard page.

However, I am hitting two issues here.. 
1) I have written dashboard.steps.ts file with all necessary implemenation required for dashboard.feature file scenario, but still getting Unimplmented exception

2) If I am using Before method in both step definition files, that is in login.steps.ts and dashboard.steps.ts then only login tests running with out issue mentioned in #1

For now, I want: 
1) Share web driver common through out tests.. that is after login tests executed need not to close browser and open new browser for dashboard tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, by default driver is getting shared. However, tests are running in parallel instead of sequential. Hence marking as answered.